# Views messing up when clearing subviews

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller

I'm pretty new, and I'm making a basic multiview application in which buttons open new views.

EDIT: I got the same problem when I made a new, simpler app, and I think it has to do with removing subviews. I made another simple version of the app, with two `UIViewController`s: `MainViewController` and `SecondViewController`. `MainView` has a toolbar and a red background, `SecondView` has a light blue background. A button on the toolbar removes all subviews with the following code (and I think this is the problem), and then adds `SecondView` as a subview.

```
for(UIView *view in self.view.subviews){
    [view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

When this runs, a similar mixing problem occurs (See below). Without this code, the subview properly appears. What's happening, and is there a way for me to remove all subviews without triggering it? My goal is to have several buttons, each opening a new views (and closing all other views).

[image]

Original post:

From the app delegate, I have the root `UIViewController` `appViewController`, attached to the  `appView` nib. This view is nothing but a yellow background and isn't intended to be displayed. Within `appViewController` I add a `RootViewController` subview on loading, which controls a `UIView` with a red background and several numbered buttons. Both views have `-(BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` written to only accept Landscape orientations.

However, when I run the application, rather than seeing the RootView's red background with buttons, the upper half of the screen is red, while the lower half is yellow with the buttons, as if the two `UIViews` are somehow getting mixed. Further, the buttons do not function, and do not even show the blue button pressed graphical effect. What's happening?

[image]

EDIT: As requested: source code for `RootViewController` The following is in the `appViewController`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    rootViewController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootView" bundle:nil];
    [self.view addSubview:rootViewController.view];
    self.rootViewController.appViewController = self;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the source code you use to add the `RootViewController` subclass?

Comment: Sorry about the delay. Source code has been posted now.

Comment: That code doesn't actually show you you're adding your controllers' views but it sounds like you are nesting the views of multiple UIViewController classes which is not how UIViewControllers are intended to be used. See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/AboutViewControllers/AboutViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH112-SW12

Comment: Oh, I see, I misread the comment. I've re-edited with the adding views. I understand that I'm doing weird stuff by making the rootViewController refer to appViewController, but I don't know how else to make the display change completely when a button is pressed.

Answer (score -2):

Shot in the dark, but perhaps:

[self configureView]

Comment: …There’s no such method on UIViewController, or anywhere else in the API. “Shot in the dark” is one thing, shooting completely blind is another.